# AS3 click event added to stage but fires when clicking on a movieclick

Tags: actionscript-3, events, click

i am a as3 newbie! I added a click event to the stage but this event also fires when i'm clicking a movieclip on the stage.

How can i make this event fire only if i click directly on the stage?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: use e.stopPropagation() and study how bubbling and cancelable works

Comment: you also should look into why you want a click event on the stage. It is generally not a good idea as you are finding out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of event bubbeling every click will also fire an stage click event. You can check in your function what the clicked target was by checking the currentTarget of the event.

```
if(e.currentTarget == stage){
     //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create layer at the bottom, add graphic that covers whole screen, convert it to symbol, add name to it and assign click event