# AS3 checking if click was on stage or an a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, target, stage

How can i check if a click was on the stage (not on a other object in front of the stage - just on a place where no other object is) or on a movieclip (name "mcSlideHolder")?

```
function onMouse_Down(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("MouseDown occured");
    trace("MouseDown target: " + e.target.name);
    trace("MouseDown target.tostring: " + e.target.toString);
    trace("MouseDown currentTarget: " + e.currentTarget);
    if(e.target.name == null || e.target.name == "mcSlideHolder")
    {   
        this._userInput();
    }
}
```

My Problem is, that e.target.name is null, when clicking on the stage.
When clicking on the mcSlideHolder e.target.name is "instance235".
How would you do this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: ok i'm sorry ... mcSlideHolder has 1 child and that "instance235" is that child. It's a bitmap object ...

Comment: Instead of comparing the value of the target display object's name property to a string value why not compare the target display object directly to another display object. For example, instead of testing `e.target.name == null`, test `e.target == stage`.

Comment: Duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062339/as3-click-event-added-to-stage-but-fires-when-clicking-on-a-movieclick

Comment: @Taurayi: As i studied thourgh that issue i now compare it with the actual stage object ... thx

Comment: @The_asMan: before i wanted to prevent the eventListener on the stage to listen to all objects on the screen ... however i realize that this is not possible and i have to check it in the event ... that's why i posted this question ... so why are you accusing me for double posting ... ???

Comment: @The_asMan: although thanks for your Help on the other post!

Comment: @haemse since I assumed you would be dead set on identifying the target objects via their `name` property I posted a work around for it, but it seems like you went with my suggestion in my earlier comment so it was a waste of time lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, when you want to detect a click on a specific MovieClip, that is the one you add the listener to:

```
mcSlideHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onSlideHolderMouseDown);
```

rather than

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouse_Down);
```

It sounds like you're doing the latter; adding a listener to the stage, and trying to figure out in the listener function what was clicked on. There is nothing wrong with this, and it can even be efficient if there are many possible things to click on. But in this case, the currentTarget is always going to be the stage, and the target is always going to be the thing you clicked on that generated the event. If that is indeed how you have things set up, you will get a different result--possibly the one you expected--if you do this:

```
mcSlideHolder.mouseChildren = false;
```

I'm assuming mcSlideHolder is the instance name. Setting mouseChildren to false will mean that mcSlideHolder will generate the MOUSE_DOWN event rather than instance235 that is its child.

Comment: ok, got it ... thanks for that explanation. The thing is, i have to listen for the stage because there are two elements on the stage and i want to listen for a click besides those elements. So what i did is (like Taurayi told) comparing the target with the actual stage object ...

Comment: Taurayi is right in his approach. You should use actual object references for identity comparisons, rather than something potentially non-unique like the .name property. It's just more robust that way.

Answer (score 2):

Adam smith's answer already explains why you get "instance235" so I'll explain a work around for `stage` object's `name` property equaling null.

You could create a wrapper class for the `stage` object and give that class a property called `name`. The wrapper class would also have to be a subclass of `EventDispatcher` so that you can override it's `addEventListener()` method and alter its functionality so that you are implicitly adding an event listener to the stage object and also to the wrapper object. The best way to explain it is to show you an example I made:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _stageWrapper:StageWrapper;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


            var stageWrapper:StageWrapper = new StageWrapper(stage, "stage");
            stageWrapper.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStageWrapperClick);

        }// end function

        private function onStageWrapperClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace(e.target.name) // output: stage

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

internal class StageWrapper extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var _stage:Stage;
    private var _name:String;
    private var _listener:Function;

    public function get stage():Stage { return _stage }
    public function get name():String { return _name }

    public function StageWrapper(stage:Stage, name:String) 
    { 
        _stage = stage;
        _name = name;

    }// end function

    override public function addEventListener(type:String, 
                                              listener:Function,
                                              useCapture:Boolean = false,
                                              priority:int = 0,
                                              useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void
    {

        super.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
        _stage.addEventListener(type, onStageEvent, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

    }// end function

    private function onStageEvent(e:Event):void 
    {
        dispatchEvent(e);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

Personally I wouldn't go with this approach but this is the best answer I can give you for the direction you seem to be going with.